# WSO2 ESB EI611 VFS ActionAfterProcess & ActionAfterFailure - options

Tags: wso2, vfs, wso2-esb

> Requirement is, not to move or delete the files after copying to a
>   different folder, leave it as it is, after copying the file and pick
>   up the latest files only

```
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">DELETE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">DELETE</parameter>
```

For inbound enpoint with `protocol="file"` the above paramaters and the options `MOVE & DELETE` are allowed. How do I add the option of `NO ACTION` ?

If this option(NO ACTION) is not possible with inbound endpoint, can we use proxy-service with `transports="vfs"` and use the no-action option? What's the syntax?

Documentation of WSO2 says, no action is possible as third option, but there's no syntax or format to it. Inbound Endpoint IDE properties, support only MOVE or DELETE. Proxy-service is a name-value pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I kinda expected that WSO2 purposely kept MOVE & DELETE as the only option, to avoid redundancy. Otherwise, the behavior or file polling will be erroneous. That's why they dropped "NONE", maybe to avoid picking up old files or files existing in the folder already. But, this should have been clear in the documentations, God, their docs is killing me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it it works in EI6, but in ESB 4.8.1 you can do it like the following.

```
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">NONE</parameter>
```

Comment: Thanks, lemme try that.

Comment: I'm interested in this, but then how does the inbound endpoint knows which file was already treated or not? Is there a mechanism for this ?

Comment: In esb 4.8.1 there's no implemented mechanism for this. The only thing you can do,is to store your processed file names somewhere (e.g. Database) and in the inSequence check if the database already contains this file. If so just skip the rest of the sequence.Keep in mind that the file will be processed everytime it is found,which might be very bad if there are a lot of files. If possible I would read the file from another directory and move it to the directory where it must stay (ActionAfterProcess parameter)